# How do you make this huge distorted analog bass/pad sound?

Tags: synthesizer, synthesis, analog

I would really appreciate information on how to create this analog sounding bass/pad sound at 0:02 and 1:13 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

The bass lead at 1:13 is just a saw wave + white noise, filtered down over time. The white noise dissappears before the saw wave, so it has its own volume envelope.

Sounds pretty much like a remix of the Stranger Things main theme. Heavily inspired by it, for sure. Nice song.